# Django : Manager isn't accessible via Process instances

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models :

```
class Process (models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=1000, primary_key=True)
    processName = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Step (models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=1000, primary_key=True)
    process = models.ForeignKey(Process, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stepName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I want to access a specific Step object. I do :

```
step=Process.objects.get(id=stepId)
```

When I try to access an objects in step :

```
step.objects.all()
```

I have the following error :

AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via Process instances

How can I access objects in step?

Answer (score 0):

get() returns a single object or instance and filter() returns a queryset.

So, here `step` is an instance of `Process` model. But manager(objects) can only be accessible via Model.

`step` itself an object. So you cannot use `step.objects.all()`

```
print(step)
print(step.processName)
```